# Are there any (potential) problems with having large gaps in auto-increment IDs in the neighbouring rows of a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mysql web app that allows users to edit personal information.

A single record is stored in the database across multiple tables.  There is a single row in one table for the record, and then additional one-to-many tables for related information.  Rows in the one-to-many tables can additionally point to other one-to-many-tables.

All this is to say, data for a single personal information record is a tree that is very spread out in the database.

To update a record, rather than trying to deal with a hodgepodge of update and delete and insert statements to address all the different information that may change from save to save, I simply delete the entire old tree, and then re-insert a new one. This is much simpler on the application side, and so far it has been working fine for me without any problems.

However I do note that some of the auto-incrementing IDs in the one-to-many tables are starting to creep higher.  It will still be decades at least before I am anywhere close to this bumping against the limits of INT, let alone BIGINT -- however I am still wondering if there are any drawbacks to this approach that I should be aware of.

So I guess my question is:  For database structures like mine, which consist of large trees of information spread across multiple tables, when updating the information, any part of which may have changed, is it ok to just delete the old tree and re-insert a new one?  Or should I be rethinking this.  IOW is it ok or not ok for there to be large gaps between the IDs of the rows in a table?

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Comment: having gaps in IDs is irrelevant to the DB. it doesn't care if you go `1, 9999, 9999999999, etc...`. they're all just numbers. it may matter to your users if they're expecting things to LOOK consecutive.

Comment: Marc B is correct.  It's a unique identifier and nothing more.  The reason to have it auto-increment, is to ensure that it really IS unique.  But the DB couldn't care less what that number is.

Comment: This is a rather broad question... and I was tempted to answer it as such, but I think it's valid to leave open... maybe move to another site though...

Answer (score -1):

If your primary keys are indexed (which they should) you shouldn't get problems, apart from the database files needing some compacting from time to time.

However the kind of data you are storing could probably stored better in a document database, like MogoDB, have you consider using one of these?